# how to handling incorrect connection on start springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc

when im trying to connect a database specifically H2 database in spring boot standalone application i'm getting:

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Wrong user name or password

that is correct behavior, the question is how can i handle this exception? this is on start the app, im trying the get the exeption on start but this exception is not catching on that.

```
try {
        Splash splash = new Splash();
        splash.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        splash.setVisible(Boolean.TRUE);

        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
                .headless(false)
                .run(args);
        splash.setVisible(Boolean.FALSE);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Error, supposed to catch error conection", ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My Spring Boot application is a console app so I don't have a splash page but I am able to catch the exception when I provide an incorrect JDBC URL or username and password in the properties file. Here is my Application.java file.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
                .headless(false)
                .run(args);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error, supposed to catch error conection");
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have the @SpringBootApplication annotation? Also are you using Hibernate or connecting directly with JDBC? It's possible the JDBC Driver is catching the exception and not throwing it to the calling application.